# How to reference C# UWP Class Library from C++ UWP App

Tags: c#, c++, uwp, win-universal-app, c++-cx

I am getting a COMException when trying to reference a method in a C# UWP class library from a C++ UWP app.  This is happening with the most basic of setups, so I must be doing something wrong.

Repro:

1. Using Visual Studio (I'm using 16.5.4), Create a new "Blank App (Universal Windows - c++/CX)"
2. Add to the solution a new "Windows Runtime Component (Universal Windows)", C#, Called "ClassLib"
3. Add this method to Class1.cs: `public static int GetNumber() { return 22; }`
4. Modify the MainPage constructor to look like this:

```
using namespace ClassLib;
MainPage::MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    auto foo = Class1::GetNumber();
}
```

5. Execute the application.   This exception happens in the MainPage constructor:

```
Exception thrown at 0x76984402 in UWPApp.exe: 
  Microsoft C++ exception: 
    Platform::COMException ^ at memory location 0x0421DD44. 
    HRESULT:0x80131040 The text associated with this error code could not be found.
```

Comment: Can the following answer help? Have you solved your issue?

Comment: Hi, Have you solved your issue? i am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is due to calling .net based WinRT components from C++/CX or C++ WinRT projects. To make it work, you can add `Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler` nuget package in your c++/cx project and install it first. Then **Right-click the project -> Unload Project -> Edit .vcxproj**. After that, adding the following properties in it.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <UseDotNetNativeToolchain Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">true</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>
    <DotNetNativeVersion>2.2.3</DotNetNativeVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**Note that**, replace the 2.2.3 version above with the version of Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler nuget package you installed. For more details about it, you can refer to this similar [thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/questions/2038/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoftappcenter.html).